# How to automate football pool checking

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking into how I can automate the process of gathering the answers from a football pool sheet. The play sheets have 2 teams per line and a box to fill in for each if the contestant believes they will win. I'd like a way where I can scan in each page and it import the data onto an excel sheet, but I haven't been able to find anything yet. Any suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[Week1 Sheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLE3A.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[Acrobat Installation File](https://get.adobe.com/reader/)

*Scan your A4 paper using a scanner to PDF*

1) Open a file in Acrobat.

2) Click on the Export PDF tool in the right pane.

3) Choose spreadsheet as your export format, and then select Microsoft Excel Workbook.

4) Click Export. If your PDF contains scanned text, Acrobat will run text recognition automatically.

5) Name the Excel file and save it in a desired location.